# Django Console App

Tags: python, django, console-application, tastypie

TastyPie seems to rely heavily on Django, and I want to develop a Python application that uses REST. I know that Django is an API for developing website, but is there a way to use Django with TastyPie as a fully console-based application?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to mix things up. Django is a framework which implements the MVC model, namely Model, View and Controller (They modify slightly this terminology, but this is a detail). It allows you to interact with a database using an ORM using models, display output data using HTML (the view, called template in Django) and to define logic to glue the model to the view (the controller, called view in Django).

Using REST, you can manipulate resources (mostly database data) using already defined keywords in the HTTP protocol.
Tastypie is a Django package allowing you to easily develop REST interfaces on your Django projects.

Django allows the [definition of commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/) callable from a console which could be pluggable with Tastypie. This answers your question but I doubt it is what you need.

If you don't need web integration (console-only application), you don't have much use of the templating part of Django nor its HTTP request handling and routing. I would suggest you to use another kind of ORM like SQLAlchemy. You could create a console interface using a library such as ncurse if you need one. Try to understand your needs first: What do you want to achieve? After answering this question, you should ask yourself: Do I need an ORM (database integration) and templating (output such as HTML)? If no, then reconsider using Django for your project and weight its pros and cons versus other frameworks more geared to fit your needs.

I would recommend clearing things in your head first since console-based applications doesn't use HTTP to communicate which is the base of the Django framework as well as the REST philosophy.

Comment: We're using Django because we have a website running for management of the database, and we want to create a console-based application using the database while using REST.

Comment: @Datacommie: Already using Django for your website and having models for your database is indeed an important point that you forgot to tell us. I understand the need for console interactivity, hence the link I provided. I don't get the REST part. You want to be able to access your REST API using the command line? Just wrap Tastypie resources in commands shown in the link I provided. That won't be using REST, though, but will offer the same features.

Comment: I will try that. I also found Slumber that should help. Thanks.